Applying a template with PnP to a SharePoint site
I am writing a script to export a template from a SharePoint site then uploading it to a different tenant.
I am using PnP PowerShell library, and I am exporting the template using this command:
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out "$outputPath\$selectedSiteName.xml" -ConnectionspConnection -Handlers Pages, PageContents

and this one to upload the template:
Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate -Path $templatePath

the export works fine, and I get an XML file, but when I try to import the template, the process gets stuck like this:
WARNING: The source site from which the template was generated had a base template ID value of ############, while the current target site has a base template ID value of ######. This could cause potential issues while applying the template.Applying template to ###########. [ClientSidePages                                    ]

what could be a probable reason for this?
I tried enabling custom script from both the source site and target but no use I tried changing the parameters and creating a brand new site but the problem still persists and I can't think of a way to debug it

When you create a site, you choose a template, a page model. Depending on your organisation's settings there may be different templates to choose among, but usually there are something like collaboration and communication site templates.
The warning you get is caused by the fact that you have created a site (your target) with a certain template, say A, but the site from which you have extracted the template (the source) was created with a template B. As the warning says this can cause issues. Recreate the target site with the same template as your source site to be on the safe side.
